# Table layout panel not resizing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have the following code, i have a `Form`, with a `Tabcontrol` on it. On the `TabControl`, I have a `TabPage` and on it I have a `TableLayoutPanel` with 3 `TextBox` and 3 `CheckBox`. I have tried all the possible measures to resize the `TableLayoutPanel` but it is not resizing. It would be great if someone points out what is the mistake I am doing in the code?. I am posting the code below:-

```
         CheckBox TitleCheckBox = new CheckBox() ; 
        TitleCheckBox.Checked = false ; 
        TextBox TextBoxTitle = new TextBox() ; 
        TextBoxTitle.Size = new Size(200,50) ;
        TextBoxTitle.Text = "Enter the title of file or folder here.";
        CheckBox ExtensionCheckBox = new CheckBox();
        ExtensionCheckBox.Checked = false; 
        TextBox TextBoxExtension = new TextBox();
        TextBoxExtension.Size = new Size(200, 50);
        TextBoxExtension.Text = "Enter the extension for file here.";
        CheckBox SizeCheckBox = new CheckBox();
        SizeCheckBox.Checked = false;
        TextBox TextBoxSize = new TextBox();
        TextBoxSize.Text = "Enter the size for file or folder here.";
        TextBoxSize.Size = new Size(200, 50); 
        TableLayoutPanel LayoutPanelGeneral = new TableLayoutPanel() ; 
        LayoutPanelGeneral.RowCount = 3 ; 
        LayoutPanelGeneral.ColumnCount = 2; 
        LayoutPanelGeneral.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize)) ; 
        LayoutPanelGeneral.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize)) ; 
        LayoutPanelGeneral.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize)) ; 
        LayoutPanelGeneral.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize)) ; 
        LayoutPanelGeneral.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize)) ; 
        LayoutPanelGeneral.Controls.Add(TextBoxTitle, 0,0) ; 
        LayoutPanelGeneral.Controls.Add(TitleCheckBox, 1,0)  ;
        LayoutPanelGeneral.Controls.Add(TextBoxExtension, 0, 1);
        LayoutPanelGeneral.Controls.Add(ExtensionCheckBox, 1, 1);
        LayoutPanelGeneral.Controls.Add(TextBoxSize, 0, 2);
        LayoutPanelGeneral.Controls.Add(SizeCheckBox, 1, 2);
        TabControl AdvancedTabControl = new TabControl();
        TabPage TabPageGeneral = new TabPage();
        TabPageGeneral.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1300, 800); 
        TabPageGeneral.Name = "TabPageGeneral";
        TabPageGeneral.Text = "General"; 
        Form AdvancedForm = new Form();
        AdvancedForm.Text = "Advanced Mode";
        AdvancedForm.MinimizeBox = false;
        AdvancedForm.MaximizeBox = false;
        TabPageGeneral.Size = AdvancedForm.Size;
        LayoutPanelGeneral.Size = TabPageGeneral.Size; 
        AdvancedForm.Controls.Add(AdvancedTabControl);
        AdvancedTabControl.TabPages.Add(TabPageGeneral); 
        TabPageGeneral.Controls.Add(LayoutPanelGeneral) ;
        AdvancedForm.ShowDialog() ;
```

Overall, I have tried the following measures:-

1) changing the `width` and `height` of `TableLayoutPanel`
2)Setting the `AutoSize` to `true` ;

Comment: Check out the `Dock` property. Setting it to `Fill` will make the child control to fill the parent. Set where appropriate to gain the results you want.

Comment: @okrumnow Thanks! I got the desired result. But can you tell why does `AutoSize` doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and solved it with:

```
((ISupportInitialize)(this.tabControl1)).BeginInit();

[...]

((ISupportInitialize)(this.tabControl1)).EndInit();
```